# Is there a better way to chain animations than this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I feel like this isn't the most effective nor efficient way of doing things:

```
    line.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: whichway}, speed-150, function() {
        title.stop(true, true).fadeIn(speed-200, function() {
            sub.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: whichway}, speed-50, function() {
                subtext.stop(true, true).show();
                paragraph.stop(true, true).slideDown(speed);
            });
        });
    });
```

whichway/speed are dynamic, but other than that it's all stuff that has to be in sync and queued up. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: This might be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a case/switch statement. Something like this:

```
function ani(step) {
    switch(step) {
        case 1:
            line.stop(true, true).show('slide', {direction: whichway}, speed-150, function() {ani(2)});
            break;
        case 2
             title.stop(true, true).fadeIn(speed-200, function() { ani(3)});
             break;


        ...

        default: ani(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing. It is a "better way" in that it's not nested code mayhem.